# SELECT only specific value from XML column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Running the following TSQL

```
SELECT Name FROM Category
```

returns these results as the column in SQL is of `xml` data type.

```
1 <locale en-US="Abstract" />
2 <locale en-US="African" />
3 <locale en-US="Americana" />
```

I'd like to get a result set like:

```
1 Abstract
2 African
3 Americana
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use  the `.value` function

```
SELECT Name.value('(/locale/@en-US)[1]','varchar(20)')
from  Category
```

[sqffiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=698c1907ca416b4879f7df3fbdacd2bf)